# Connecting to a database in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

I'm afraid I have been stuck on this one for a couple days now. 
I've worked with databases before (normally using php and a mysql server) but I'm new to visual studio and I just can't seem to find much info on what kind of server you need to connect to (and how).

I guess the first part of my question would be: Can the server running the database be a remotely hosted "online" mysql server or does it have to be installed on your machine (for example like you can install apache)?
The easiest option for me would probably be to connect to my existing mysql server of my online website, but how?

I have sql server management studio installed but am not sure what to enter as the server name etc in the dialog box that shows up.

I do know my mysql server details and all, but just have no idea how where and how or even if I can connect it directly to my visual studio project.
I have looked several times on google but till now I have only been able to find videos and tutorials showing how to create a new **database** - which assume you are already connected to some sort of server.

Also, if you do use a locally hosted database server then wouldn't you have to port it to a different (online) database once the website goes live?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the database can be remotely hosted, I'have this working on my local machine with a remote MsSql database. Make sure the remote database server accepts connections from your IP.

I'm pretty sure the MsSql Server Management Studio is only for MsSql, not MySql. The server name in my case is the IP for the remote MsSql database server, further you need the login and password for your database. But if you use your remote MySql, you don't need this tool.

I have no experience with MySql, but it must be possible to use the database in your Visual Studio project with the correct "connectionstring". The connectionstring contains the type of the database, where it is located, login and pasword, etc. You can find the syntax of you connectionstring here: www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/